# Ionic Appflow: Deploy to Google Play only creates Draft, how to release directly?

Tags: continuous-integration, google-play, ionic-appflow

For my app, I've setup Ionic AppFlow and have it automatically deploy to Google Play. Unfortunately, the process only creates a release draft which I have to manually release in the Google Play Console.

Is there a way to automate away the manual release step, so that deployments from AppFlow to Google Play are "live" immediately?

Comment: me too having same issue . it s ended up with draft mode

Comment: I've asked the support and they confirmed that this is intended behavior. Looks like nothing can be done here :/

Comment: yes. i m also raise a support from support. still no response